# Accessing nested child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

After using xmltextreader for a while and finding that 'use linq' is pretty much the answer to every .net xml related problem on here I decided to give it a go and thus far it's been really good, however the documents I'm working with are a bit odd so now I've got a bit of a problem.

A simplified version of what I'm working with;

```
<a>
  <b name="..." id=".">
    <c id="..." type="...">
        <value_I_want>.....</value_I_want>
    </c>
    <c id="..." type="...">
        <value_I_want>.....</value_I_want>
    </c>
```

I need to query 'a' to get at the attributes and element of each instance of 'c' - I can't query 'b' because it's not unique and would return a bunch of irrelevant stuff.

I should probably mention that the 'a' element is not the ultimate root of the document.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all the `'c'` elements at once with a Linq query:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("<yourxml/>"); 
var c_elements = doc.Descendants("a")
                    .Descendants("b")
                    .Descendants("c);
```

Now do whatever you want from extracting attribute or selecting any child node.

Comment: `.Descendants` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so `.OfType<XElement>()` is unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't know you could chain the descendant method like that, works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

use linq  ;-)

You want to use the Descendants method rather than the Elements method.  Something like this:

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("<yourxml/>"); 
        var celes = xdoc.Descendants("a").Descendants("c");
```

This will first find all elements "a", then look in that collection to find all elements "c".  This may or may not be what you want.  To ensure you have the right parentage you can do this:

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("<yourxml/>");
        var celes = xdoc.Descendants("c")
                        .Where(x => (x.Parent != null) && (x.Parent.Name == "b"))
                        .Where(x => (x.Parent.Parent != null) && (x.Parent.Parent.Name == "a"));
```

Comment: [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) has an [`Ancestors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348268.aspx) method, which returns all the ancestors. To check the first and second parents, you could do something like this: `.Where(x => {var l = x.Ancestors.Take(2).ToList(); return l.Count==2 && l[0].Name == "b" && l[1].Name == "a";})`